# Angular: Changing controller to a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

Using the code below I cannot return an object to the return values in the factory and subsequently have blank fields in the html, with the angular error.

> Provider 'theService' must return a value from $get factory method.

I'm working on a single page app using TingoDB (a javascript version of Mongo) and Angular for data-binding in Node-Webkit.

I can query the database from within a controller to display, filter data etc. for a web page but want to change this code into an Angular factory so I can synchronise across a number of controllers.
 Although I am able to return data from the factory to the controller using dummy data I have been unable to return 'live' data from the database.

The following code works as a controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
function getData(callback) {
    collection.find( {} ).toArray(function(err, docs) {
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            callback(docs);
          });
        });  
}

function info(b) {
    // console.log(b);
    $scope.items = b;
}

getData(info);

}]);
```

Changing this to a factory doesn't work:

```
    app.factory("theService", function($scope) {
    function getData(callback) {
        collection.find( {} )).toArray(function(err, docs) {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                callback(docs);
              });
            });  
    }

    function info(b) {
        // console.log(b);
        $scope.users = b;

        return {
            all: $scope.users,
            first: $scope.users[0]
        }
    }   
    getData(info);  
});
```

The controller:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, theService) {
  $scope.users = theService.all();
});
```

Comment: you need to be a bit more descriptive than "doesn't work"

Comment: Factories must return something

Comment: @user3801428 can you please create plunk or fiddle, there are lot of unknown variables that make code look messy

Comment: The code pulls data from a local database and runs in node webkit so I don't think it is possible to make make a plunk or fiddle that retains its integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the controller, don't know where you define `collection` variable, but it's better to pass values to the factory

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','getData', function ($scope, getData) {  
    $scope.items = [];

    getData(collection).then(function(items) { // pass "collection" to the factory
        $scope.items = items;
    });
}]);
```

It's better to use factories as `global` functions (*or class constructors*)

```
app.factory('getData', ['$q', function ($q) { // you can't inject $scope to the factory        
    return function getData(collection) {
        var defer = $q.defer(); // let's make it work more in angular way, use promises

        collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) { // fixme - don't really know how to handle exception here
                defer.reject(err);
            } else {
               defer.resolve(docs);
            }            
        });

        return defer.promise;                
    };
}]);
```